# Redirecionamento de página usando input HTML e JS

Tags: java, html, css, front-end

Estou tentando fazer um projeto para meu portfólio mas estou com algumas dificuldades.

Estou tentando criar uma página HTML que pega o número de celular digitado em um input e cria uma URL redirecionando para uma conversa no WhatsApp.

```
<input type="tel" class="telefone" placeholder="(00) 00000-0000" />
    <script>
        var numero = document.querySelector(".telefone");
        var tel = numero.value.toString();

        function mudarPagina(){
            window.location.href = "https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=55" + tel;
        }
    </script>

    <input type="button" onclick="mudarPagina()" value="Enviar"/>
</body>
```

Estou tentando usar o window.location.href para redirecionar a página, mas o código utilizando uma variável (tel) não está funcionando.

Sabem me dizer o que está errado no código?

Answer (score -3):

No seu código, a variável número está pegando o número do telefone no momento em que a página é carregada. Para pegar o número digitado, precisa colocar dentro da função, da seguinte forma:

```
function mudarPagina(){
    var numero = document.querySelector(".telefone");
    var tel = numero.value.toString();
    window.location.href = "https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=55" + tel;
}
```

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigado!!!!

Comment: Lembre-se de marcar a minha resposta.